# Express server can't read key in Docker container

Tags: docker, express, ssh-keygen

I am dockerizing a system that uses a pem and key to authenticate with a remote dev server. Unfortunately, it would appear that it is unable to find the file despite it being in the docker image.

Error

```
server_1   | Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/certificates/jwt.key'
server_1   |     at Object.openSync (fs.js:497:3)
server_1   |     at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:393:35)
server_1   |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/controllers/user.js:7:16)
server_1   |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
server_1   |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
server_1   |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
server_1   |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
server_1   |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
server_1   |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
server_1   |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/upload.js:8:24)
server_1   |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
server_1   |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
server_1   |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
server_1   |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
server_1   |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
server_1   |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18) {
server_1   |   errno: -2,
server_1   |   syscall: 'open',
server_1   |   code: 'ENOENT',
server_1   |   path: '/app/certificates/jwt.key'
server_1   | }
```

Line (server/controllers/user.js -> app/controllers/user.js)

```js
const pem = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../certificates/jwt.key"));
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14
RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run get_key
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

package.json

```js
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha -r dotenv/config ./**/*.test.js",
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon -r dotenv/config server.js",
    "get_key": "ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM -f ./certificates/jwt.key -P ''"
  },
```

[image]

Comment: When you run the container, do you have any volume mappings on /app/ or /app/certificates/ path?

Comment: @HansKilian wow is that it then? I do in my docker compose. So perhaps it overwrites it blank after the image build? I will try without the volume mount. It was 1am so I might have missed this.

Comment: @HansKilian That was totally it! Note to self don't code past midnight xD

Comment: Yes, a volume mapping hides whatever is in the image on that path. See the second bullet point here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/#tips-for-using-bind-mounts-or-volumes

Answer (score 0):

The volume mount was overriding the key building. Need to generate the key locally first before composing.

```
  server:
    build: server
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
```